# problem in starting a background thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a backgorund thread that extends AsyncTask and which I use in activity to read some data from a DB.

I use this background thread in order for not to get my app blocked because of the big amount of data that needs to be retrieved.

Usually I start the thread this way:

```
public void onResume(){

init_task.execute(db);

}



 public class InitTask extends AsyncTask<DBAdapter, GeoPoint, Void> {

...some code here....


}



    protected void onPause() {
        init_task.cancel(true);
        super.onPause();
    }
```

The point is that I start the thread in onResume() and cancel it in onPause()

But now I have a different problem.

I have an autocomplete that displays a dropdown list and when I click on one of these entries I wanna start the backround thread(the data that I retrieve now from DB depends on the item that I click on).

Well for that I've implemented a listener and I start the thread there....The problem is that the listener is onCreate() so I can't use onResume() inside onCReate() ....

Now my problem is that I don't know how to stop the thread cause once I leave the activity it still retrieves data from my DB...and I want it to stop.

Here is a diagram of my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


                init_task = new InitTask();
                init_task.execute(db);

            }

        });


}

public class InitTask extends AsyncTask<DBAdapter, GeoPoint, Void> {


}
```

Question: Where should I stop my thread so as soon as I leave the activity it stops retrieving data from the DB......and after I come back it starts again!!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the task to instance field and check it for null before calling cancel.

In your activity class (not onCreate() method)

```
InitTask initTask=null;
```

in onPause()

```
if (initTask!=null) {
    initTask.cancel(true);
    initTask=null;
 }
```

Rest is the same.

Comment: What do u mean to instance field cause I don't get it....I'm quite new to this!Could u put a small example with what u mean so I can understand?

Comment: But I start my thread in onCreate()....U say that it's ok to start it in onCreate() only that this line:InitTask initTask=null;
 should be in my Activity???I got it right?

Comment: yes, it's ok. Make sure that you don' declare initTask second time in method.

Comment: I think it's wotking.Here u have an extrapoint and your accept.Cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you can't still access your init_task? In your scheme there are no any visible restrictions on cancelling AsyncTask instance you have created in a listener.

To deal with restarting you can save some flag and continue fetching after activity is resumed.

Comment: Ya,...no restrictions,but where should I cancel it????Because I tried cancelling in onDestroy() but it still doesn't get cancelled and I still retrieve data from DB????The question is:WHERE to cancel it?